# SwiftUI UISearchController searchResultsController navigation stack issue

Tags: swift, swiftui, ios13, uisearchcontroller

I have UISearchController that's been made `UIViewControllerRepresentable` for SwiftUI, as follows:

```
struct SearchViewController<Content: View>: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    var content: () -> Content
    let searchResultsView = SearchResultsView()

    init(@ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.content = content
    }

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UINavigationController {

        let rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: content())
        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: rootViewController)
        let searchResultsController = UIHostingController(rootView: searchResultsView)

        // Set nav properties
        navigationController.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        navigationController.definesPresentationContext = true

        // Create search controller
        let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: searchResultsController)
        searchController.searchBar.autocapitalizationType = .none
        searchController.delegate =  context.coordinator
        searchController.searchBar.delegate = context.coordinator // Monitor when the search button is tapped.

        // Create default view
        rootViewController.navigationItem.searchController = searchController
        rootViewController.title = "Search"

        return navigationController
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<SearchViewController>) {
        //
    }
}
```

This works, and displays the `searchResultsController` when the user is searching. However, the `searchResultsController` doesn't seem to know it's navigational context/stack, so I can't navigate from that list view in the `searchResultsController`.

Can this be structured to allow navigation from `searchResultsController`, or is this currently a SwiftUI limitation.

Any advice is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I recently also need to implement this feature(search bar like navigation bar) in my app. Looking you snippets really inspired m2! **My Thanks First!**

After learning from you, [ula1990](https://github.com/ula1990/SearchBar-Programmatically), [Lorenzo Boaro](https://www.raywenderlich.com/4363809-uisearchcontroller-tutorial-getting-started) and [V8tr](https://github.com/V8tr/MixingSwiftUIAndUIKit), I implemented my own.

I set the `searchResultsController` to `nil` (due to untappable navigation link in it, so i set it to nil).

[Demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AP6I2.gif)

Code:

```
struct SearchController<Result: View>: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    @Binding var searchText: String
    private var content: (_ searchText:String)->Result
    
    private var searchBarPlaceholder: String
    

    init(_ searchBarPlaceholder: String = "", searchedText: Binding<String>,
         resultView: @escaping (_ searchText:String) -> Result) {
        self.content = resultView
        self._searchText = searchedText
        self.searchBarPlaceholder = searchBarPlaceholder
    }
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UINavigationController {
        let contentViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: SearchResultView(result: $searchText, content: content))
        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: contentViewController)
        
        let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = context.coordinator
        searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false // for results
        searchController.searchBar.placeholder = searchBarPlaceholder
        
        contentViewController.title = "\\(Title)" // for customization
        contentViewController.navigationItem.searchController = searchController
        contentViewController.navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = true
        contentViewController.definesPresentationContext = true
        
        searchController.searchBar.delegate = context.coordinator
        
        return navigationController
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UINavigationController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<SearchController>) {
        // 
        
    }
}
extension SearchController {
    func makeCoordinator() -> SearchController<Result>.Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UISearchResultsUpdating, UISearchBarDelegate {
        var parent: SearchController
        init(_ parent: SearchController){self.parent = parent}
        
        // MARK: - UISearchResultsUpdating
        func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
            self.parent.searchText = searchController.searchBar.text!
        }
        
        // MARK: - UISearchBarDelegate
        func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
            self.parent.searchText = ""
        }

        func searchBarShouldBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) -> Bool {
            self.parent.searchText = ""
            return true
        }
    }
}

// "nofity" the result content about the searchText
struct SearchResultView<Content: View>: View { 
    @Binding var searchText: String
    private var content: (_ searchText:String)->Content
    init(result searchText: Binding<String>, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping (_ searchText:String) -> Content) {
        self._searchText = searchText
        self.content = content
    }
    var body: some View {
        content(searchText)
    }
}
```

I don't if this is what you want, but thanks again!.

Comment: Could you provide a usage example please? Thanks

Comment: @nmdias for the demo shown above: check the snippets [here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/9J2Dy8zTDH/). It may be buggy, but u'll get the idea.

Comment: @EthanMengoreo the snippet is gone :(

Answer (score 1):

## (EDIT) iOS 15+:

iOS 15 added the new property `.searchable()` (here is [the official guide](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/adding-a-search-interface-to-your-app) on how to use it). You should use it instead unless you still need to target iOS 14 or below.

## Original:

I just made [a package](https://github.com/thislooksfun/SwiftlySearch) that would likely solve this issue. It's similar to @EthanMengoreo's answer, but has (in my opinion) a more SwiftUI-like syntax.

I'm also including the full relevant source code for v1.0.0 here for those who dislike links or just want to copy/paste (I am not keeping this in sync with any updates to the GitHub repo).

Extension:

```swift
// Copyright © 2020 thislooksfun
// Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
// of this software and associated documentation files (the “Software”), to deal
// in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
// to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
// copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
// furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
//
// The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
// all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
//
// THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED “AS IS”, WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
// IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
// FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
// AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
// LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
// OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE
// SOFTWARE.

import SwiftUI
import Combine

public extension View {
    public func navigationBarSearch(_ searchText: Binding<String>) -> some View {
        return overlay(SearchBar(text: searchText).frame(width: 0, height: 0))
    }
}

fileprivate struct SearchBar: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    @Binding
    var text: String
    
    init(text: Binding<String>) {
        self._text = text
    }
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> SearchBarWrapperController {
        return SearchBarWrapperController()
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ controller: SearchBarWrapperController, context: Context) {
        controller.searchController = context.coordinator.searchController
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(text: $text)
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UISearchResultsUpdating {
        @Binding
        var text: String
        let searchController: UISearchController
        
        private var subscription: AnyCancellable?
        
        init(text: Binding<String>) {
            self._text = text
            self.searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
            
            super.init()
            
            searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
            searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = true
            searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
            
            self.searchController.searchBar.text = self.text
            self.subscription = self.text.publisher.sink { _ in
                self.searchController.searchBar.text = self.text
            }
        }
        
        deinit {
            self.subscription?.cancel()
        }
        
        func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
            guard let text = searchController.searchBar.text else { return }
            self.text = text
        }
    }
    
    class SearchBarWrapperController: UIViewController {
        var searchController: UISearchController? {
            didSet {
                self.parent?.navigationItem.searchController = searchController
            }
        }
        
        override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
            self.parent?.navigationItem.searchController = searchController
        }
        override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
            self.parent?.navigationItem.searchController = searchController
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```swift
import SwiftlySearch

struct MRE: View {
  let items: [String]

  @State
  var searchText = ""

  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      List(items.filter { $0.localizedStandardContains(searchText) }) { item in
        Text(item)
      }.navigationBarSearch(self.$searchText)
    }
  }
}
```